# Executing SQL query in Golang

Tags: database, go, prepared-statement

I've seen two ways of people executing queries using Golang builtin `database/sql` queries. One of them is using `fmt.Sprintf`:

```
func (db *DB) CreateUserTable() (sql.Result, error) {
    statement := "CREATE TABLE %s (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    v := []interface{}{"User", "ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL", "Name varchar(100) UNIQUE", "Email varchar(100) UNIQUE", "Address varchar(100) ",  "Username varchar(100) UNIQUE"}
    return db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf(statement, v...))
}
```

and the other one is using prepared statement:

```
func (db *DB) CreateUserTable() (sql.Result, error) {    
    statement, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO User(tbl1,tbl2,tbl3) VALUES(?,?,?)")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return statement.Exec("value1", "value2", "value3")
}
```

The first gives benefit by enabling you to dynamically set the table name, column name, and the values. But the second one only for values. What's the difference? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Never** build SQL from strings that come from outside your system.

[image]

*Always* use the `?` syntax.

If you must set SQL parts like table names, prepare multiple, complete SQL statements that contain `?` for the values. Select the SQL to execute, maybe based on user input, but **never** build SQL *from* user input.

Answer (score 3):

It is cleaner to use prepared statements so that whenever a requirement changes you can easily modify the statements. Also to prevent SQL injections.

> Prepared statements is much better than concatenating strings, for all
>   the usual reasons (avoiding SQL injection attacks, for example).
>
> In MySQL, the parameter placeholder is ?, and in PostgreSQL it is $N,
>   where N is a number. SQLite accepts either of these.

One more thing is Prepared statements can be used for repetitive approach, can be executed multiple times and can be destroyed.

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("select id, name from users where id = ?")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer stmt.Close() // closing the statement
rows, err := stmt.Query(1)
```

And you are using interfaces

```
func (db *DB) CreateUserTable() (sql.Result, error) {
    statement := "CREATE TABLE %s (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    v := []interface{}{"User", "ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL", "Name varchar(100) UNIQUE", "Email varchar(100) UNIQUE", "Address varchar(100) ",  "Username varchar(100) UNIQUE"}
    return db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf(statement, v...))
}
```

which can take any type of parameter under the hood which can be vulnerable

For more detailed information Go for this [Link](http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html)